# React calculator: check if any value exists in string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there anyway I could check if more than one value exists in a string? My idea is to have only two conditions: 
a) if there´s no decimal, add it;
b) if there´s an operator (+-*/) followed by a number from 0 to 9, add it. 
The decimal gets added only when one of those two conditions are met. What string method could I use?

```
handleDecimal(evt){
const result = evt.target.value;
let value = this.state.value;
if (value.indexOf('.') === -1){
 this.setState(prevState => ({
        value: this.state.value + result
   }))};
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "add it"? Do you mean add some numbers together, or insert a decimal point (at what position?), or what? Can you give a couple of examples?

Comment: In the current handle event, if the decimal isn´t there, the decimal gets added. I want something similar to that, but the condition should be something like "set the state with a decimal only if the decimal doesn´t exist already OR if there´s an operator followed by a number". For instance: if the string is "2322399838", you can add a decimal to it (just one). If, after that, there´s a "+2293998" you can add another decimal and so on. Hopefully I´m being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and String.prototype.search() to accomplish this.

The RegEx `/([-+*/]\d)/` will match an operator followed by any digit.

If you want to add a decimal even when there exists a decimal, but there is also an operator followed by a number:

```
if (value.indexOf === '-1' || value.search(/([-+*/]\d)/) > -1) { //add decimal }
```

If you want to have only one decimal at most in the final string:

```
if (value.indexOf === '-1') { 
    //add decimal 
} else if (value.search(/([-+*/]\d)/) > -1) { 
    //add decimal 
}
```